# The SO User Avatar Image: Stored in the Database or the File System?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, architecture

Is the Stackoverflow avatar image stored in the database?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. The image is from Gravatar, who stores it. All SOFU does is provide the email hash for the Gravatar.

Comment: As for how it is stored on Gravatar, it is anybody's guess.

Comment: Pretty sure they use 1's and 0's like everyone else.